# Reading partitioned topics on Apache Pulsar

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, cqrs, event-sourcing, apache-pulsar

I'm trying to select between pulsar and kafka for an **event sourcing/cqrs** scenario, so one very important feature for these kind of systems is to replay messages from a time point or offset.

With **Kafka** is simple, you just have to indicate from what point to start consume, or simply seek from a start point.

But **pulsar** works different, in addition to the consumer interface it has another one called read interface for reading messages from an start point, like beggining or id, but it doesn't work with partitioned topics.

My question is, how can I read from a partitioned topic on Pulsar? could I specify a start point to a consumer since read interface doesn't work for partitioned topics?

I'm testing these features on nodejs clients, so let me know if I'm lossing some feature because of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to read from a specific partition, put this when setting the topic on the consumer:

```
.topic(yourTopicName-partition-N)
```

Where `yourTopicName` is a partitioned topic and `N` the required partition to read from.

In **`node.js`** format, it should look like this, f.e, if you want to read from partition 1:

```
const consumer = await client.subscribe({
  topic: 'mytopic-partition-1',
  subscription: 'my-subscription',
});
```

Comment: Yeah worked thanks! now my question is how can I  keep the order of messages by key when I add more partitions to a topic, I think I'll need to create a new topic version when I need more partitions to keep the ordering guarantee.